# Sorting arrays: second last

Tags: php

```
ksort ($votes);
        foreach ($votes as $total => $contestant){
        $ordervotes[]= $contestant;
        } 

        echo "<li> And the winner is: {$ordervotes[4]}</li>";
        echo "<li> And the loser is: {$ordervotes[0]}</li>";
        echo "<li> {$ordervotes[1]} came second last</li>";
```

This works fine when none of the '$total's are the same, if they are the same i get an error code. I realise I could use the 'max/min' to get the first and last elements of the array, but how do i go about finding the second last?

Thank you

Joe

Comment: @WayneWhitty its just a guess, but I think that the array element might not be defined in some cases.

Comment: Why waste valuable time sorting? O(NlogN)? Max is O(N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try:

```
echo $votes[count($votes)-2];
```

You also don't need to populate another array with the same values - you can keep them in `$votes`. You might also want to look into sorting your array [by value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) instead of [by key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) (which I assume you're trying to do).

---

If you're expecting duplicate keys, you need to remodel the way you're storing your data. Consider using a multidimensional array:

```
$votes = array(
   array('name'=>'John','vote'=>10),
   array('name'=>'James','vote'=>11),
   array('name'=>'Jimmy','vote'=>13),
);
```

You will be able to sort this array using this function and code:

```
// This function will sort your array
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}

// Sort the array by the 'vote' key
aasort($votes,"vote");

// Echo out the name of the second-last person
echo $votes[count($votes)-2]['name'];
```

Comment: Why waste valuable time sorting? O(NlogN)? Max is O(N).

Comment: The OP didn't say he was using associative arrays. He's echoing the array values out as strings (or anything non-array based)

Comment: This won't work if $total is the same. It gives an error code. Also I don't need the number of votes I need the name of the contestant.

Comment: This looks like it should work but I'm struggling to get my head round it. Sorry I'm a beginner!

Comment: Try implementing it, and if you run into difficulties let us know. All you're doing is changing the way your array is structured, and using a function to sort it. Don't worry about how complex the function looks

Comment: Does this work if for example there are two $votes with the same value? eg $votes = (12, 6, 8, 13, 8);

Comment: @JoeAustin Yes - that's why I recommended you change your array structure. Before, duplicate values was breaking it

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function secondMax($arr) {
    $max = $second = 0;
    $maxKey = $secondKey = null;

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if($value > $max) {
            $second = $max;
            $secondKey = $maxKey;
            $max = $value;
            $maxKey = $key;
        } elseif($value > $secondMax) {
            $second = $value;
            $secondKey = $key;
        }
    }

    return array($secondKey, $second);
}
```

Usage:

$second = secondMax($votes);

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it by using the function count:

```
$ordervotes[ (count($ordervotes)-2) ]
// the array starts with index 0, so (count($ordervotes)-1) is the last element
```

Comment: Why waste valuable time sorting? O(NlogN)? Max is O(N).

Comment: @JoeAustin I don't get it, in your example you put $contestant in the $ordervotes, and my line greps the second last (in case there are at least two elements in).

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong here. Trying to get my head round it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is in your `$votes` variable ... How could you have multiple contestants with the same votes (and so, with the same key).

I think there is a mistake here.

You $votes should be like this :

```
$votes = array(
    'contestant 1' => 8,
    'contestant 2' => 12,
    'contestant 3' => 3
);
```

Then order the array : `sort($votes)`

Finaly, get the second last : `$votes[count($votes) - 2];`

Comment: $votes = array(          $joe => "Contestant 1", 
$colm => "Contestant 2",  $eoin => "Contestant 3", 
$cian => "Contestant 4",  $john => "Contestant 5" );

Comment: This gives the number of votes- not the name of the contestant

Comment: I really don't understand your $votes ... What are the value od $joe, $colm ... ? The number of votes ? And what if 2 votes are the same ? You can't use a non-unique key for an array.